# onPostExecute does not open Intent

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Basically I'm using AsyncTask to show a `progressBar`, and after the `progress` is `10`, it should run a method which is located in `MainActivity`. When the `progressBar` is `10/10` it results in a crash on the following error.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

**MapProgressTask**

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textView.setText(result);
    button.setEnabled(true);
    progressDialog.hide();
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.getGooglePlace();
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void getGooglePlace()
    {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent;
        try {
            intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, place_picker_request);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can you tell me how can I run that method when the `progressBar` is full please? Thanks!

Comment: MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();? What are you trying to do?

Comment: never try to instantiate your activity to execute a method inside this activity. Create that method inside a public seperated class....

Comment: **Never** create an instance of an activity yourself. So, first, delete these lines: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();    mainActivity.getGooglePlace();`. Then, decide upon a better plan for starting up this other activity (e.g., `static` method taking a `Context` as a parameter). Be sure to take into account the possibility of configuration changes while your `AsyncTask` is running (e.g., user rotates the screen).

Answer (score 2):

In your onPostExecute event, you need to add a flag before starting the activity , when you are starting the activity from a non-activity class:

```
protected void getGooglePlace()
{
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Intent intent;
    try {
        intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Needed when starting an activity from a non-activity class
        startActivityForResult(intent, place_picker_request);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is needed for this case. That is needed, as your comment indicates, when the activity is being started by a non-activity `Context`, and we have no evidence that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, there is no need to instantiate your activity. As it's a bad decision. You can put your async task as a nested class to your activity and call getGooglePlace() method, but this is also a bad idea. I would suggest the following approach.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private WeekReference<MyListener> mListener;

    public MyTask(MyListener listener) {
      mListener= new WeakReference<MyListener>(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      MyListener activity = mListener.get();
      if (activity != null) {
      // do your stuff with activity here
      }
    }
  }
```